# Problems using Apache Camel and spring-ws

Tags: java, web-services, apache-camel, spring-ws

I am trying to call a Web Service using Apache Camel and Spring-ws but I get an error message saying:

```
org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: The message with To '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.  Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree.
```

I have created a WebServiceTemplate in spring:

```
<bean id="soapMessageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">
        <property name="soapVersion">
            <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapVersion.SOAP_12"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="soapMessageFactory"/>
        <property name="messageSender" ref="messageSender"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="messageSender" class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender">
        <property name="credentials">
            <bean class="org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials">
                <constructor-arg value="user:secret"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

And I try to call the web service using the dsl like this:

```
.to("spring-ws:https://WS-URI?webServiceTemplate=webServiceTemplate")
```

Any ideas on what this error could depend on and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: What is the content of the message body?

Comment: The body is a very simple xml generated by a jaxb marshalling. It contains only one field.I dont have my work computer here right now but I can paste it here later tonight if that helps.